# Angular 4 SEO with Nginx and Docker

Tags: angular, nginx, seo, prerender

I have a rather general question related to SEO for Angular 4. I read about the issues with crawling SPAs, while on the other hand people where claiming that Google would have no issues at all. I wonder what the best strategy is to start with, against the backdrop that I use a production setup that is build on Nginx and Docker. I would like to have the following questions answered:

1)I heard of Angular Universal for server-side rendering, however I guess this approach is bound to using the express-server package? I use a Nginx, does it make an difference in production? How would i set this up with docker?

2) Alternatively, I heard of the possibility to use [prerender](https://prerender.io/) together with Nginx and Docker (prerenderer used only for crawlers). Is this suitable for Angular 4? That would be the most straightforward way in my case I thought ...

3) Is it even necessary to prerender the page? What are the main drivers in todays SEO? Is Google really capable to crawl SPAs? AFAIK, metatags do not have that great impact anymore ....

Thank you all

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score 0):

Angular Universal is not bound to express, you can render to any output you want ( file, stream etc. ).

Here's an example of rendering directly to file:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import { renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { join } from 'path';
import { readFileSync, writeFileSync, mkdirSync } from 'fs';

enableProdMode();

const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

const template = readFileSync(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser','index.html')).toString();
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory } = require('main.server');


renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, { document: template, url: '/' })
  .then(html => {
    writeFileSync(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html'), html);
   }
);
```

The resulting index.html contains the HTML that otherwise would be generated angular in the browser, and is much easier for search crawlers to pick up than having to render the pages themselves. Even though google most probably is capable of doing this, others are not - and your page rank will be affected by how efficient your site can be crawled.